# Get value form input

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I am learning Javascript and trying to get user input value from input.

In my project, I have a few inputs form and want to get the number value from each input. I saw some questions asking similar stuff, and I tried some DOM but none of them worked to my code.

I tried document.getElementsByName()

```
let userInput =      document.getElementsByName('moneyamount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value);

console.log(inputNum); //result is NaN
```

I also tried document.querySelector()

```
let userInput =     document.querySelector('#money-amount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value);

console.log(inputNum)
```

which worked perfect, but I need to get value from a few inputs, so querySelector will not be good for this situation. so I tried document.querySelectorAll() as well, however,

let userInput = document.querySelectorAll('#money-amount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value)

console.log(inputNum)// result is NaN

I am not sure what DOM I should use in this situation. I need to select all elements and need to get value from them.

This is my HTML of input.

```
      <input
        class="input money"
        type="number"
        id="money-amount"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        name="moneyamount"
        required
      />
      <input
        class="input money"
        type="number"
        id="money-amount1"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        name="moneyamount"
        required
      />
      <input
        class="input money"
        type="number"
        id="money-amount2"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        name="moneyamount"
        required
      />
```

I hope you guys could help this problem.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList. That means that you need to iterate through the list before attempting to access the value of individual elements. Since all your input elements have the class `input money`, then you can use the selector to retrieve all their values:

```
let userInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input.money');

userInputs.forEach(userInput => {
  console.log(parseInt(userInput.value));
});
```

To collect all their values, you will likely have to map them to an array, for which you can do this:

```
let userInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input.money');

let values = Array.from(userInputs).map(userInput => parseINt(userInput.value));
console.log(values);
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let userInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input.money');
  
  userInputs.forEach(userInput => {
    console.log(parseInt(userInput.value));
  });
  
  let values = Array.from(userInputs).map(userInput => parseInt(userInput.value));
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<input class="input money" type="number" id="money-amount" placeholder="Enter amount" name="moneyamount" required value="123" />
<input class="input money" type="number" id="money-amount1" placeholder="Enter amount" name="moneyamount" required value="456" />
<input class="input money" type="number" id="money-amount2" placeholder="Enter amount" name="moneyamount" required value="789" />

<button type="button" id="btn">Get money amounts</button>
```

Comment: Hi Terry, Thanks for your answer. both of them worked perfect! great to know to get values with different way. Thanks again!

Comment: @NagisaAndo No problem: glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName` doesnot mean use the name attribute of input HTML element.

It mean use it by input name like this:

```
 let userInput = document.getElementsByName('input');
```

But its not of your use because it will all the three elements, You can use `document.getElementById.` Please find the example below:

```
let userInput = document.getElementsByName('money-amount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value);

console.log(inputNum)
```

Comment: Thank you Prince, I totally misunderstood of how to use document.getElementsByName. Thank you for the correction:)!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to access multiple-element with one query you should try to use the `class` not `id` or `name`

`id` & `name` should be unique in each page

```js
var allMoney = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
console.log(allMoney[0].value);
console.log(allMoney[1].value);
console.log(allMoney[2].value);
```

```html
<input
        class="input money"
        type="number"
        id="money-amount"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        name="moneyamount"
        value="1"
        required
      />
      <input
        class="input money"
        type="number"
        id="money-amount1"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        name="moneyamount"
        value="2"
        required
      />
      <input
        class="input money"
        type="number"
        id="money-amount2"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        name="moneyamount"
        value="3"
        required
      />
```

Comment: Hi RIcky, Thanks for your help it worked great! And also thanks for explaining me about how to use querySelecter differently.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList. When you use `document.querySelectorAll('input')`, all three nodes will return in a NodeList format:

`[input#money-amount.input.money, input.#money-amount1.input.money, input#money-amount2.input.money]`

Where # represents the id of the element and . represents the class of the element. The individual elements can then be accessed by using their indexes. i.e `document.querySeletorAll('input')[0]` would give you the first element in the NodeList, `document.querySeletorAll('input')[1]` would give you the second element, etc. The indexes can also be defined as constants so its much easier to read than using 0,1,2. 

 For example, `const cost = 0, document.querySelectorAll('input')[cost]`.

You can test the commands out within the console of the Chrome Developer tools. This will give you a better visual of what elements you're selecting and what values are returning by calling different methods.